# Hydration error in Nextjs with sharpspring form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, sharpspring

I'm getting an error when trying to insert a form that is coming from an external tool in Nextjs, more specifically Sharpspring, and the error in question is the way I'm inserting it in the HTML, as it returns an iFrame, I need to create one parent tag with a certain ID, so that the sharpspring script can insert the form, and in that tag, it returns this error:

```
Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <iframe> in <section>.
```

Script and parent tag code to serve the form

```js
<script
  /* Sharpspring params */
/>
<script
  defer
  src="https://koi-3QNTJUXTN6.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=2.0.1"
/>

/* ... */

<section id="target" title="Newsletter" />
```

I'm using React in version 18.2.0 and Next in version 13.1.2.